# Como funciona o processo de desenvolvimento de uma gramática?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática

Como funciona o processo do desenvolvimento de uma gramática?

Comment: Bem-vindo, Pedro! Essa pergunta é interessante, mas muito ampla. É preciso uma questão mais específica (e sobre português - a versão atual caberia melhor no [site irmão de linguística](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)) para que seja on-topic aqui.

Comment: Aliás, a pergunta é sobre a criação de uma gramática artificial ou sobre a evolução histórica de uma gramática?

Comment: Pedro, o tema é mesmo muito amplo, uma área de pesquisa com décadas de resultados e discussões. Não sou usuário do [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), mas eles têm uma tag "[resource-request](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request?sort=votes&pageSize=15)" que sugere que eles estariam abertos a um pedido por referências como o teu. E essa sua pergunta onde estamos comentando, eu sugeriria que você transformasse também num pedido de referências sobre o assunto específicas do português.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para início de “conversa” é necessário saber o que é e como entendemos a gramática. Todos nós sabemos falar e nos comunicarmos tranquilamente. Nos entendemos e nos fazemos entender. Sendo assim, a gramática seria ou é o conjunto dos conhecimentos que nos permitem esse entendimento, a expressão e a comunicação do nosso pensamento. E isso nada tem a ver com os conhecidos livros que tratam de verbos e substantivos, de advérbios e  adjetivos, preposições e conjunções.
É sabido que existem os escritores, revisores, editores, os lingüísticos e os etimólogos, ou seja, muitas pessoas que passam a vida estudando  para que tenhamos uma gramática de qualidade. Desta feita, isso tudo se inicia com as lingüísticas mais rústicas, naturais e básicas possíveis. 
Dito isso, as primeiras letras, palavras, paginas, capítulos começam com fonética, a sonoridade das palavras, em seguida as mais simples, vogais, consoantes, pronomes, verbos, substantivos. Nos textos seqüenciais, estes elementos começam a ser misturados formando frases até  alcançamos os aspectos mais complexos de uma escrita. E  por fim, as sintaxes, as composições de elevado nível lingüístico. 
Mas, não podemos nos esquecer que pelo meio também são necessários investigações, estudos e pesquisas sociais, assim, se faz necessário consultas a bibliotecas, para entender como a gramática vai encaixar no público alvo. E tem mais, para as gramáticas mais robustas e complexas é necessário adotar estudos influentes em outras línguas, também é preciso tentar separar o atual do arcaico, de forma a ter um trabalho final de qualidade e duradoura no tempo para que possamos de fato falar e entender a gramática.
[enter link description here](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%C3%A1tica)

[enter link description here](https://www.todamateria.com.br/gramatica/)
[enter link description here](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/gramatica/)
Para saber mais
[image]

[image]